# Is there a way to keep this referenced in a callback?

Tags: javascript, callback, dom-events

Hard to explain with words, but here is what I quite often have in my code:

```
var self_reference;
self_reference = this;

$(selector).bind('event', function() {
  self_reference.someFunction();
});
```

Is there a way to write that without the need of a temporary variable (self_reference here) ?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

`this` is context sensitive and `this` will be a different object inside the callback function. Unless you copy it somewhere it will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the jQuery [proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function.

e.g.

```
$.getJSON(url, $.proxy(function()
{
  // this has now got the desired context
}, this));
```

Comment: `call` is no good - you have to pass the value in at invoke time, and if you don't copy it to a temp variable it is lost. I would assume that jQuery's proxy is just a wrapper that effectively makes a temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(selector).bind('event', (function() {
  this.someFunction();
}).bind(this));
```

[`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is an ES5 extension to function.

You could use [`_.bind`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bind) as a cross browser alternative or use [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/).

```
$(selector).bind('event', (_.bind(function() {
  this.someFunction();
}, this));

$(selector).bind('event', ($.proxy(function() {
  this.someFunction();
}, this));
```